# winform show windows to Foreground replace temporary form dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForm program,have two Form.form1 is main form,watch a socket port.when  Request  arrive,show from1:

```
 this.Show();
 this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

and when user click form1's button,I hide from1 show form2:

```
        this.Hide();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false; 
        From2 form = new     From2 (info);       
        var value = form.ShowDialog();
```

So far so normal.when From2 click OK,I want show Form1 again,but Form1 Often be covered by other programs:

```
if (DialogResult.OK == value)
        {
            reponse();
        }

         this.Show();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

I want form1 show seems to  replace form2 position.how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `ShowDialog` passing the current form as the owner:

```
var value = form.ShowDialog(this);
```

Do this instead of hiding `form1`. This keeps the two forms linked together in the windows Z-Order and automatically disables input on `form1` whilst `form2` is displayed on top of it. So when the time comes for the user to perform any activity of `form2`, even if it had previously been lost in the Z-Order, when they bring `form2` to the front, `form1` will come forwards also.